# When using "ddl-auto=update" how to prevent error output when table already exists?

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

In my application.properties I am using

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

now I am using this with an existing database so in the logfile there are a lot of messages that that a table aready exists.

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: There is already an object named 'MyTable' in the database.
```

is there a way to prevent this output in the log? I am using log4j2 as logging framework.

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

with

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```